# Generating 5 unique coordinates on a grid using 2 arrays

Tags: random, grid, coordinates, unique

I am using Java to program an application that randomly generates 8 X points in a 5x5 grid.

Both the x and y axis have separate arrays I use to store the coordinates. These 2 arrays are parallel arrays that correlate with each other. The problem I am having is I can not seem to generate 8 ***unique*** coordinates.

For example, no matter what I do, I will eventually only have less than 8 unique coordinates because it so happens that the same coordinates are generated twice. 
I am trying to find an algorithm that can ensure the 8 random generated coordinates to be unique.

Also, For some reason, when I use the Random class to generate random numbers between 1 - 5, I sometimes get a 0 as a randomly generated number.
This is how I use the Random class:

Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
coordinate = rand.nextInt(5)+1;

Thank you all for your time!

code:

```
int[] co1 = new int[8];
    int[] co2 = new int[8];
    ArrayList<Integer> uniqueCo1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> uniqueCo2=  new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 8 ; i++)
    {
        co1[i] = rand.nextInt((5)+1);
        co2[i] = rand.nextInt((5)+1);
        while(co1[i] == 0 || co2[i] == 0)
        {
            coord1[i] = rand.nextInt((5)+1);
            coord2[i] = rand.nextInt((5)+1);
        }
        int j = 0;
        for(int q = 0; q < acceptedCoord1.size() || j < acceptedCoord2.size(); q++)
        {
            while(co1[i] == uniqueCo1.get(q) && co2[i] == uniqueCo1.get(j))
            {
                co1[i] = rand.nextInt((5)+1);
                co2[i] = rand.nextInt((5)+1);
            }
                j++;
        }
        uniqueCo1.add(co1[i]);
        uniqueCo2.add(co2[i]);
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a code sample to illustrate your question.

Comment: Thank you for informing me. The concerning code has been posted.